# Postgresql inner join or subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

In terms of performance, when comparing these two queries, which one should be more efficient?

```
select d.list_name, d.date_created,d.price
p.name, p.stock_quantity  
from price_list d inner join product p on d.product_id = p.product_id;
```

OR

```
select d.list_name, d.date_created,d.price,
       (select p.name from product p where p.product_id = d.product_id ),
       (select p.stock_quantity from product p where p.product_id = d.product_id )
from price_list d;
```

I thought that the join would be inneficient, each table has ~ 10M records, but after a few test I found that the second option is performing better. Is this possible?

Comment: Note: there is a `,` missing in your second query.

Comment: If it is happening, then it must be possible.  If you want more information, look at the EXPLAIN ANALYZE plans for both queries, and if you still have questions, show them to us.

Comment: Okey, yes I would look at the explain analyze but it was more of a general question actually. I was told that inner joins are not optimal and that I should try to avoid them when I have the chance, but I'm having second thoughts on that. I don't think that accessing the same table over and over (on the subquery) can perform better than the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

These queries do different things.

`INNER JOIN` can:

- Filter rows when there are no matches.
- Produce multiple rows when there are multiple matches.

You should actually use the version that does what you intend.

If your data is structured so that the results are the same, then I would expect the performance to be quite similar.  In particular, for both you want indexes on `product_id` in all the tables.

However, it is always worth running the queries on your data on your system and comparing the execution plans.

Comment: Yes, actually results are the same for both queries.